# How to detect user country based on time zone

Tags: inno-setup

How I can use inno script language to detect the user country, where he is present, based on the time zone settings of PC.

I simply need to know if user is from USA  or outside USA.

Comment: You can check Time Zone setting in registry: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation`. You can also call `TZUTIL.exe` with parameter `/g` and copy `result` as `Variable`.

Comment: There is no one to one mapping of time zones to country. You can check for -5 to -8 to get a rough idea but it won't be accurate.

Comment: @RobeN, you should use native API functions as much as you can, since only those ensecure, that even when this registry key will be moved somewhere in next OS release for instance, that API function will still get the proper information, just from the new location. For this case it is the [`GetTimeZoneInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724421(v=vs.85).aspx) function. But to determine, if the user is from U.S.A., I wouldn't rely on the time zone (user can be e.g. on holiday, out of his inland timezone, thus he can also temporarily change the timezone).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on time zone settings, but on geographical location instead. For list of values returned by the [`GetUserGeoID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318138%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function see the [`Table of Geographical Locations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Code]
const
  GEOCLASS_NATION = 16;
  GEOID_UNITED_STATES = $F4;
type
  GEOID = Longint;
  GEOCLASS = DWORD;

function GetUserGeoID(GeoClass: GEOCLASS): GEOID;
  external 'GetUserGeoID@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function IsGeoLocationUSA: Boolean;
begin
  Result := GetUserGeoID(GEOCLASS_NATION) = GEOID_UNITED_STATES;
end;

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  if IsGeoLocationUSA then
    MsgBox('Geographical location U.S.A.', mbInformation, MB_OK)
  else
    MsgBox('Geographical location other than U.S.A.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Forgot to notice, that the minimum supported client OS for this function is Windows XP. For those, who don't know, where this setting comes from, is here a picture of the Region and Language control panel applet from Windows 7. Geographical location checked in the above function, can be configured there:

[image]

Comment: It is possible to use the [`delayload`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptdll.htm#delayload) option, which disables the automatic function import check at startup. Then you can wrap the function call to a `try..except` block and once you'll call the function and it won't be available or the import will be wrong, it will fall into the exception block.

Comment: And yes, the [`GetUserGeoID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318138%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would fail on Windows 2k. I wasn't hoping that you'll be supporting Windows 2k, so I didn't noticed anything about Windows XP as a required minimum. I don't even know, if there was setting [`like this`](http://www.integration.co.nz/images/win7-locale.png) in Windows 2k.

Comment: +1 for remebering the API. I knew it existed but was too lazy to look it up :)